# Excel Query date range for Value

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, conditional-formatting, countif

Trying to query an excel document to determine the number of times a value appears so I can put in conditional formatting on and heat map to determine the number of times the resource is busy during a date.

I have Jan1-Dec31 in individual cells I need to query data split among three colums as follows

```
       A       B       C
      Jan1    Jan12   Bob
      Jan2    Jan10   Roger
      Jan11   Jan14   Bob
```

The formula needs to use the start date in column A and end date in column B and count the resource name occurrence in column C.

So my output would go into my Heat Map as follows.

```
        Bob  Roger
 Jan1    1    0

 Jan2    1    1

 Jan3    1    1

 Jan4    1    1

 Jan5    1    1

 Jan6    1    1

 Jan7    1    1

 Jan8    1    1

 Jan9    1    1

 Jan10   1    1

 Jan11   2    0

 Jan12   2    0

 Jan13   1    0

 Jan14   1    0
```

If if could expanded without having to make 365 formulas for each resource that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* I'm understanding your question properly. The way I'm interpreting it is that you're looking for a way to expand your "heat map" input, but I may be reading it wrong. Let me know if I'm mistaken.

This is a classic case of where SUMPRODUCT is awesome.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($E2>=$A$2:$A$4)*($E2<=$B$2:$B$4)*(F$1=$C$2:$C$4))
```

Which you can copy over and down (see image). You'll obviously need to edit your ranges accordingly to fit your real data.

It works like this. Consider Bob's 1/1/2016. It takes the date and compares the date to the start date, and creates an array of true/false based on whether or not the date is greater than or equal to the start dates in the start date array. Then it does the same, less than or equal to the end dates in the end date array. Then it checks the resource array for Bobs. At the end, you have three arrays:

{TRUE, FALSE, FALSE} * {TRUE, TRUE, TRUE} * {TRUE, FALSE, TRUE} -> {TRUE, FALSE, FALSE}. The * is an AND operator, so any place where TRUE, TRUE, TRUE occurs is a 1 and if any FALSE occurs its a zero. Then, it coerces your TRUE, FALSE, FALSE array to 1, 0, 0 and sums the result!

[image]

Edit: Here's a way to tackle what we're talking about in the comments.

[image]

Comment: I was able to get the formula to work on cells that contain only that persons name. Thank you. How would I incorporate if there was a cell with multiple entries. For example if Bob and Roger were both in the same cell on C5 but seperated with a comma? Also the data would referenced on a separate sheet so I am not sure where to put the sheet reference. Here is my current string.                                                                           =SUMPRODUCT(--($A3>='Project Plan'!$D$2:$D$2000)*($A3<='Project Plan'!$E$2:$E$2000)*($B$1='Project Plan'!$G$2:$G$2000))

Comment: It is also worth noting that the cells are groups to expand and collapse. There are dates which are valued through a formula. Not sure if it would matter but using: =MAX(E319:E331)

Comment: @compguy101101 I think you can split Resource using text to columns and still do the same formula, over the newly minted columns. If they're stored like "Roger, Bob, Tim" then you'll need to trim the resulting columns (since if you split on , they'll break into " Bob"). I think you might be able to split on ", " but I didn't check. You'd just change C4 to D4 if that makes sense. Let me know if it doesn't and I can post a picture showing what I mean.

Comment: @compguy101101 Alternatively, if you don't want to split the columns, you can try this: =SUMPRODUCT(--($D2>=$A$2:$A$4)*($D2<=$B$2:$B$4)*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(E$1,$C$2:$C$4)))) which should work to look through the column.

Comment: @compguy101101 I put a screenshot at the bottom of the post that shows the "SEARCH" one

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(--($D2>=$A$2:$A$4)*($D2<=$B$2:$B$4)*(ISNUMBER(SE‌​ARCH(E$1,$C$2:$C$4))‌​))        This worked perfect. I was able to keep my columns and have them sum into my heat map. Looks great. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem, glad it worked out for you!